# How is CiviCRM in a Drupal Commons Install?

Tags: wordpress, drupal, civimember, webform-civicrm

My organization has been using WordPress, and wants to move to Drupal for views and webform, but we need some sort of social community for our members. We're currently using PeepSo (from the makers of Jomsocial for Joomla! (peepso.com)) which we like better than BuddyPress. However, what can we use to give us similar functionality in Drupal? The only thing we've found is Drupal Commons.  Are there any conflicts between CiviCRM and Drupal Commons? If there are conflicts, is there another way to have a social community on Drupal that won't conflict with CiviCRM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There would be no conflicts. I think the question of what makes a good drupal 'social community' is a specific drupal question and should be asked on that StackExchange, however if you want more specific answers here it would be helpful if you clarify in your question what you want the system to offer users.

Having used Commons once (due to someone elses choices) but eg Organic Groups many times, I would not opt for a pre-built system like Commons. But again that is not a discussion for CiviCRM SE really.